# Some functions in "os" package misbehaves when taking imported variables as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I have a ***config*** file from which some values are being read using `configparser`, one of which is `PROJECT_PATH`

The ***config-reading*** happens in a ***separate python file*** which is **imported** to `main.py`

The ***aim*** is to **list all the directories** present in the `PROJECT_PATH`

To do that, I'm using `os.listdir()` which gives an **error**.

```
>>> os.listdir(PROJECT_PATH)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"/home/user/projects/"'
```

But, if I pass the `path` hardcoded, like: `os.listdir("/home/user/projects")` then it **works correctly** and shows the directories. 

I also tried using `os.path.exists()` and similar problem occurs:

```
>>> os.path.exists(PROJECT_PATH)
False
>>> os.path.exists("/home/user/projects")
True
```

---

Now, the funnier thing is this:
When I'm creating a **local variable** say `prj_path` and storing the path value inside there, it **works**.

```
>>> prj_path = "/home/user/projects/"
>>> os.path.exists(prj_path)
True
```

However, if I store the **imported** variable `PROJECT_PATH` into a **local** variable, and use it, it doesn't work. 
I also tried other things, like typecasting again `str(PROJECT_PATH)` and this also **doesn't** work.

> Basically, any operation using the imported variable `PROJECT_PATH` **DOESN'T** work, but using only local variables, and/or hardcoded strings work!

---

I also tried using the `pathlib` module to generate path from string: `pathlib.Path(PROJECT_PATH)`

This also doesn't work. 
**No operations using the imported string works when passed to any of the aforementioned functions.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the double quotes are part of the value of the config variable loaded from the config file. This is suggested by the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"/home/user/projects/"'
```

Remove the surrounding quotes from the path value in the config file, or strip them before use. I would prefer the former as that requires less corrective code.

Comment: I also thought that, and I tried many ways to remove that, none are working. 
It always gives the same error.

Comment: Have you looked in the config file?. Are the parhs defined with surrounding double quotes. They are definitely being introduced some where/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it works after using the `strip('"')`
The paths are defined using surrounding double quotes in the config file. The takeaway for me is that "be mindful of double quotes in the config file"

Comment: But adding `strip` to your code to correct the config file is probably not the best way to go. Removing the quotes from the config file is the correct fix for this problem. `ConfigParser()` properly handles whitespace within the config key's values so why add unnecessary code?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will remove quote from config file for fixing this properly.

Comment: @biplobmanna: that's sensible. You should probably update the accepted answer if you agree that this a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: `No such file or directory: '"/home/user/projects/"'`

The actual path is surrounded by extra double quotes and doesn't exist.

Strip could do the job:

```
>>> '"/home/user/projects/"'
'"/home/user/projects/"'
>>> '"/home/user/projects/"'.strip('"')
'/home/user/projects/'
```

Comment: I tried it, and the same problem persists. `strip()` gives the same error.

Comment: Unless you show the whole code including `strip()` call, we won't be able to find out what is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis-tried previously. I forgot to use `strip('"')` and hence it was not working, now it works! Thanks for the reply! It's such a simple problem, but was causing me a headache for a while now!